# Create PostgreSQL 9.3 index on json column through python, django, south?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, django-south

I have a json column and I need to add an index like that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table ((column->'nest1'->'nest2'->'nest3'->>'data_to_index'));
```

This works PERFECTLY if I execute the sql from lets say pgAdmin III. The problem is that I need to create the index on a django south migration.

So, what I'm doing in the migration file is:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    ...
    db.execute("""CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table ((xml->'nest1'->'nest2'->'nest3'->>'data_to_index'))""")
```

But the index is not created after the migration.

I actually tried this in a lot of different ways like using psycopg2 directly, loading and executing an sql file... nothing works!

Can someone help me?

Thank you!